# JSF, multiple bean update property in a form

Tags: java, jsf, properties, javabeans

I edited my question to be more precise as I have more time to write it.

I have a JSF form that should modify the value of the different properties of a dog :

```
<h:form id="submit">
     <h:outputLabel value="Dog name:"/>
     <h:inputText value="#{User.dog.name}" id="dogName"/>
     <h:outputLabel value="Name :"/>
     <h:inputSecret value="#{User.name}" id="name" />
     <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

This is my managed bean `User.java` :
(All the getter and setter are good and valid, as this is a bean constructor is empty).
(Initially Dog property is initialized in a validation method, so it has a value and is `not null`)

```
public class User {
    public User() {}
    String  name;
    Dog dog;

    (...get, set, ect...)
```

This is an other bean that I have not set managed as it is only used by User class 
`Dog.java` :

```
public class Dog{
    public User() {}
    String  dog_name;

(...)
```

*Offcourse this is a simple exemple for understanding the thing.*

When I send the form, `User.name` property will update but not the `User.dog.name` property.

*How can both java classes' values be updated ?*

After the form is submitted I show the current values, only the `User.name` has changed :

System.out.println(User.name); //value changed after form is submitted
System.out.println(User.dog.name); //value NOT changed after form is submitted

I dont know if you understand my problem here, I want to manipulate the Dog class properties within my JSF form althouth I wont modify the Dog bean directly, only the `User.Dog`...

By the way, faces-config is ok :

EDIT :
I have added a  for my User managed bean. Although, nothing is changed...

```
<managed-property>
    <property-name>dog</property-name>
    <property-class>package.Dog</property-class>
    <value>#{Dog}</value>
</managed-property>
```

Comment: Correct your question - your Dog class class is declared as User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preinstantiate the nested beans during construction or initialization of the parent beans. JSF won't do that for you.

So instead of:

```
public class User {
    Dog dog;
}
```

you need to instantiate it directly:

```
public class User {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
}
```

or in constructor:

```
public class User {
    Dog dog;
    public User() {
        this.dog = new Dog();
    }
}
```

or if `Dog` is actually a managed bean, inject it as managed property in `User` by `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>dog</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Dog</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.User</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>dog</property-name>
        <value>#{dog}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

In this all I assume that your properties and getters and setters are named according the [Javabean naming conventions](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon I get home. This is what happens when you must complete a full project without any useful knowledge I am ending school but the teacher only told us about simple JSP. Nothing can be done simply in JSP when we refer to a big and complete application. Thanks, I confirm this solution when I arrive home ;) ! (I  didn't know about <managed-property> tag. This is what we call : learning Hibernate, JSF, JSTL and Ajax the same week. Pretty good for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I suggest to run the code through a debugger but my first guess would be that `User.dog` is `null`. Also, I'm a bit wary by the upper case bean name `User`. That should be `user` (unless you're referring to static fields in the class `User` which would be a terrible mistake in a JSF environment).